# How to fix exception in setResultTransformer method during Hibernate 4 using with MS SQL 2008?

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, nullpointerexception, named-query

How to fix exception in setResultTransformer method during Hibernate using?

I have method which calls named query

```
SessionFactory sf =  HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Query  qr = session.getNamedQuery("Product_Create");
        qr.setParameter("@Return", 0); 
        qr.setParameter("@ProdIDID", 0);
        qr.setParameter("@PassID", new BigInteger("9999999999"));
        qr.setParameter("@Amount", new BigInteger("7777777777"));

        t.commit();
        List<CreatedCardBean> list = qr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CreatedCardBean.class)).list(); 
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            CreatedCardBean card = (CreatedCardBean)list.get(i);
            LOG.info(String.valueOf(card.getCardId()));
        }
```

MS SQL procedure looks like:

```
PROCEDURE Product_Create(
        @Return  int  output,
        @ProdID numeric(18,0)  output,
        @PassID numeric(18,0),
        @Amount numeric(18,2))
```

My hibernate config looks like:

```
    <hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://....</property>
    <property name="connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
    <!--<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> -->

    <mapping resource="com/comp/common/Product_Create.hbm.xml"></mapping>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and hibernate-mapping looks

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <sql-query name="Product_Create" callable="true">
        <return-scalar column = "retVal" type="int"/>
        <return-scalar column = "cardId" type="long"/>
        <![CDATA[{CALL Product_Create (:@Return, :@ProdID, :@PassID, :@Amount)}]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I run the method it create a product (aim of procedure) in db, but after it shows the exception :

```
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,775] annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,788] org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,791] hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,794] hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,828] hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,828] hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
WARN : [окт-06 11:49:56,861] util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,888] hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/comp/common/Product_Create.hbm.xml
WARN : [окт-06 11:49:56,919] util.xml.DTDEntityResolver - HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
...
...
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:56,953] hibernate.cfg.Configuration - HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
WARN : [окт-06 11:49:57,091] connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:57,202] connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:57,204] connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:57,895] hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:57,986] transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:57,992] internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : [окт-06 11:49:58,056] internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
Hibernate: {CALL Product_Create (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}
WARN : [окт-06 11:50:02,280] jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: S0001
....
WARN : [окт-06 11:50:02,301] jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ProductID = 78712878
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:950)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
```

Could anybody help me with idea to fix this Exception?

**UPDATE** 
CreatedCardBean is:

```
public class CreatedCardBean {
        private int ReturnValue;
        private long prodID;

        public int getReturnValue() {
            return ReturnValue;
        }
        public void setReturnValue(int returnValue) {
            ReturnValue = returnValue;
        }
        public long getProdID() {
            return prodID;
        }
        public void setProdID(long prodID) {
            this.prodID = prodID;
        }
}
```

Comment: may be there is some exception being thrown from the `stored procedure`

Comment: try to close transaction after query execution.

Comment: There is not close method in transacrion classt. I added session.close() but the  problem still occurs. Stored procedure works without any exception.

Comment: It seems my code can not catch output parameters and put them into CreatedCardBean. Help still needed.